# how to retrieve question from firestore firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve the data from firestore instead of retrieve from project file itself(in vscode). But, it keeps giving error. Do i need to use stream builder for this? Below is the question I have set in firestore.

[image: this is the image of questions i have set in firestore database]

below is the code. I got an error at line " return ActionButton".

```
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  const Quiz({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('questions')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }

                final questionDocs = snapshot.data!.docs;
                final questions = questionDocs
                    .map((e) => Question.fromQueryDocumentSnapshot(e))
                    .toList();

                 return ActionButton(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
                      ),
                      
                    );
                  },
                  title: 'Start',
                );
              },
              ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please update your question with the code (as text) and error.

Comment: I have put the code above. I got an error at line 'return ActionButton'

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a streambuilder, but a futurebuilder can be handy:
[here is an example from the official docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read)